# jQuery method doesn't work with appended data and delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this table body:

```
<tbody class="resultado" id="lista">

</tbody>
```

Then I "fill" it using

```
$('.resultado').html(data);
```

The 'data' variable comes from Ajax.
One of the columns is

```
<td>
     <div class="qtd" style="width: 60px;">
         <input id="qtd{{$produto->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="quantidade" >
     </div>
 </td>
```

This input, when I press enter, calls this method:

```
$(document).on('keyup','.qtd' ,function(event)
{
    var tecla = event.which;

    if (tecla === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var columns = row.find('td');

}
```

If I fill the tbody statically using a foreach it works, but it doesn't work when I create them dynamically using the html() method.

```
var value = $(this).attr("value");
```

Results in undefined or garbage even though I'm using event delegation, or am I?
Thanks

Added snippet. The goal is to type a value in the input box and show it on the alert

```js
//Enter 
$(document).on('keyup','input' ,function(event)
{
    var tecla = event.which;
    
    if (tecla === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // var value = e.target.getAttribute('value');
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        alert (value);
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var columns = row.find('td');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <th class="w-50">Material</th>
                    <th>Unidade</th>
                    <th>Estoque</th>
                    <th class="w-25">Preço</th>
                    <th>Qtd</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="resultado" id="lista">
                   
                </tbody>
                
                <script> 
                
                data = '<tr><td>nome</td><td>unidade</td><td><div class="qtd" style="width: 60px;"><input id="qtd{{$produto->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="quantidade" ></div></td></tr>';
                
                 $('.resultado').html(data);
                
                </script>
```

Comment: The column you have a snippet of, I assume it is properly nested in a `<tr>`?

Comment: why are you listening to key up on a div and not the input?

Comment: @Taplar Yes it's wrappepd on a tr

Comment: @epascarello It  seemed more logic to me, but listening on input also doesn't work

Comment: K, so try changing `var value = $(this).attr("value");` to `var value = $(this).val()`; and see if anything changes

Comment: so you are actaully appending full table rows with html? And you should be using .value() and not .attr()

Comment: Taking the snippet and changing the attr() to val(), it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be binding on the input and you should not read the attr to get the value.

```js
$("#lista").on('keyup', '.qtd input', function(event) {
  var tecla = event.which;
  if (tecla === 13) {
    var input = $(this)
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = input.val();
    var row = input.closest('tr');
    var columns = row.find('td');
    console.log(value);
  }
})


var data = new Array(5).fill('<tr><td class="qtd"><input/></td></tr>').join('');
$('.resultado').html(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="resultado" id="lista">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It works now, thank you. But now 'var row = input.closest('tr');' isn't getting the right value. But that is another problem.

Comment: not sure how that would not be getting the right value.... You mean it is not selecting the correct row?

Answer (score -2):

You most likely want to get the value property, not the value attribute.  The attribute stays the same as what it was when it was added to the DOM.  The property changes.

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.value, e.target.getAttribute('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Original Value">
```

Comment: Can you edit your question, Click the `<>` button or type Ctrl+M to bring up the on site snippet tool, and create a working example of the issue?  Because getting the value property should work in a delegate event handler. @JeanMorrison

Comment: added it and put a description @Taplar

Comment: @JeanMorrison I took your snippet, changed `.attr('value')` to `.val()` and the alert showed the value.